# C++ Vector is modified twice than it should in Computational Geometry

Tags: c++, algorithm, computational-geometry

I am trying to solve the following problem. I have 2 sphere-like polyhedrons, as in the following image, and I am trying to find the triangles of each model which are either within the other model, or intersecting with it. In order to achieve that I have developed a geometric algorithm, where I start a ray from each vertex of the model and check how many times it intersects with the other model. If the number is odd, then the vertex is within the other model, and if the number is even, it is outside.

[image: The 2 models]

The problem occurs when I try to distinguish between the triangles that are fully inside the other model, and the intersecting ones. In order to do that, I use the following logic:

- For each vertex that is inside the other model, I check all the triangles of the same model and try to find the triangles this vertex belongs to.
- When I find such a triangle, I add 1 to the same index in the counter vector.
- In the end I want to check the number of vertices each triangle has withing the other model. If it has 3, it is an inside triangle, if it has 1-2 it is an intersecting one, and if it has 0 it is an outer one.

The problem is that the following code, which seems to simulate that procedure, gets the counter values up to 6. That shouldn't be happening, since each triangle can only have 3 vertices.

[image: Results of counter vector]

The image is in the format, counter[ti] value for ti.

I would be really thankful if someone could pinpoint the problem for me! Also, any ideas to improve my code are welcome. Thank you in advance.

```
    //create a vector to keep how many vertices are inside the other model for each triangle
    std::vector<int> counter(triangles.size());
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < counter.size(); i++){
        counter[i] = 0;
    }

    //check for every vertex of the model whether it is inside the other model
    for (unsigned vi = 0; vi < vertices.size(); vi++)
    {   

        Vec3d &ver = vertices[vi];
        vec myVec(ver.x, ver.y, ver.z);
        Ray myRay(myVec, myVec.Normalized());
        int interCount = 0;
        for (unsigned ti = 0; ti < triangles2.size(); ti++){
            vec v1, v2, v3;
            v1.x = triangles2[ti].v1().x; v1.y = triangles2[ti].v1().y; v1.z = triangles2[ti].v1().z;
            v2.x = triangles2[ti].v2().x; v2.y = triangles2[ti].v2().y; v2.z = triangles2[ti].v2().z;
            v3.x = triangles2[ti].v3().x; v3.y = triangles2[ti].v3().y; v3.z = triangles2[ti].v3().z;
            math::Triangle tri(v1,v2,v3);
            if (myRay.Intersects(tri)){
                interCount++;
            }
        }
        //if it is inside, find the triangles that have this vertex
        //and add 1 to the respective index in the counter
        if (interCount%2!=0){
            for (int ti = 0; ti < triangles.size(); ti++){
                bool isOnTri = false;
                vvr::Triangle &tri = triangles[ti];
                if ((tri.v1().x == ver.x && tri.v1().y == ver.y && tri.v1().z == ver.z) && isOnTri == false){
                    isOnTri = true;
                }
                else if ((tri.v2().x == ver.x && tri.v2().y == ver.y && tri.v2().z == ver.z) && isOnTri == false){
                    isOnTri = true;
                }
                else if ((tri.v3().x == ver.x && tri.v3().y == ver.y && tri.v3().z == ver.z) && isOnTri == false){
                    isOnTri = true;
                }
                if (isOnTri){
                    counter[ti] ++;
                }
                isOnTri = false;
            }
        }
    }

    //put the triangles in the proper struct
    cout << "\n";
    for (int ti = 0; ti < triangles.size(); ti++){
        cout << counter[ti] << " for " << ti << " ";
        vvr::Triangle &tri = triangles[ti];
        vvr::Triangle3D m_tri(tri.v1().x, tri.v1().y, tri.v1().z,
            tri.v2().x, tri.v2().y, tri.v2().z,
            tri.v3().x, tri.v3().y, tri.v3().z, Colour::blue);
        m_tri.setSolidRender(true);
        if (counter[ti]==5 || counter[ti] == 6){
            m_tris_inner.push_back(m_tri);
        }
        else if (counter[ti]>0 && counter[ti]<5){
            m_tris_intersect.push_back(m_tri);
        }
        else if (counter[ti]==0){
            m_tris_outer.push_back(m_tri);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Strong hunch: when you generate the model, you start from an icosahedron and recursively subdivide its triangles using midpoint subdivision. However you aren't sharing the midpoint vertices of neighbouring triangles. Therefore you have duplicate vertices in your vertex list, which means that the triangle counts get incremented twice, once for each of them since the equality tests for x y z will be true for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, a likely reason that your counter values are greater than 3 is that there are duplicate vertices in the vertex list, so the count will get updated when both of them are processed. Since the counter for a triangle gets incremented when any vertex equal to any of its vertices intersects the object, if there are 2 copies of each vertex with the same co-ordinates then the counter will be incremented 6 times.

One possible way this could be coming about is if you are generating the model by starting from an icosahedron and recursively subdividing its triangles using midpoint subdivision, without sharing the midpoint vertices of neighbouring triangles.

The way to fix this would be to check for duplicates when you generate the  vertices before adding a new one to the list, however there are a few optimizations you can make to your code which will make this irrelevant.

To begin with, you can optimize your intersection tests by computing a bounding box for all the vertices in `triangles2`, before you begin the outer loop. You can do this just by iterating over all the vertices and finding the min and max x y and z. Then when you are testing each vertex in `vertices`, first check if its x y z values are inside the range given by the bounding box for `triangles2`, and if not then it's not possible for it to intersect and you can skip this loop:

```
for (unsigned ti = 0; ti < triangles2.size(); ti++)
```

Alternatively, you could calculate a bounding sphere and do a point-to-sphere test. It is also possible to do some special case tests based on the near-spherical geometry of your objects - all the triangles that partially intersect will lie on a plane. However a bounding box is a good general purpose optimization that works well for most arbitrary shapes. If you calculate a bounding box for both objects then you can test if they overlap at the very start of your function and if they don't then you immediately know that none of the vertices intersect.

The second change you can make is to store 3 indices into your `vertices` array inside `triangles`, instead of storing 3 copies of the vertices. Don't loop through all the triangles after you have found each intersecting vertex, but instead store `interCount` into an array with one entry for each vertex. Once you have finished iterating over all the vertices, then iterate over the triangles in a separate loop:

```
for (int ti = 0; ti < triangles.size(); ti++)
```

and use the 3 vertex indices stored with each triangle to look up the 3 corresponding values in `interCount`, and make a count of how many odd values there are. If it's 0 then the triangle is entirely outside the other object. If it's 3 then it's entirely inside. If it's 1 or 2 then it's partially intersecting the surface.

Doing it this way will be faster because you don't have to check each vertex for each triangle for each vertex, and also you don't have to worry about counting more than 3 vertices, because you only have 3 indices.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was a very keen observation, to pinpoint the duplicate vertices. Your suggestions are also amazing, and I am going to put them in effect immediately.